# Change colors in fullcalendar 5.7 based on alternating rows -- which element for nth-child?

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

There have been posts on this.  I have done this:

```
.fc table tr td:nth-child(odd) {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    background: rgba(240,240,247,1);
    font-size: 1em
}
```

(also tried with .fc-scrollgrid -- all the same)

but that gives the 2 colors on alternating columns, not rows, since the tr's go by weekday.

So one post (from 5 years ago) which suggests

```
.fc-day-grid > div.fc-row:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: #CCC;
}
```

says:

> Also, you need to target the series of  elements which represent
> the rows - they are not a table. They're inside a table, and there are
> more tables inside them, but the rows themselves are actually `<div>`s
> (you can see this when you inspect the rendered HTML of the calendar
> using your browser tools).

But when I look in the browser at these events in the browser, I don't see any divs in there.  I don't know which element to target to get this to work.

I am trying to apply this to the month view (dayGridMonth) in fullCalendar 5.7

Any ideas? -- Thanks

Comment: Thanks for you answer, and sorry for putting my comment in the wrong place.  It looks like an incredible answer.  However, I must be missing something because it had no effect.  This statement:

Answer (score 0):

In the dayGridMonth view in fullCalendar 5.x, each row in the grid has the following HTML:

```
<tr role="row">
```

These are within a `<tbody role="presentation">` table body element (to distinguish them from other `<tr>`s such as the column heading row, which have the same row).

This can be seen by looking at the calendar's generated HTML using a browser's element inspector tool.

So you can target the alternating rows with a CSS rule something like this:

```
.fc-dayGridMonth-view tbody[role=presentation] tr[role=row]:nth-child(odd)
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/mdxJYpp

Comment: Thanks for your answer; sorry for misplacing the comment. Looks like an incredible answer. I must be missing something because it had no effect.  The statement referring to the <tbody role="presentation"> where you say that it can be seen by looking at the calendar's generated HTML using the element inspector -- I looked all over the html in the inspect tool, and I never see anything related to rows at all.  This is undoubtedly why adding your .css sample had no effect.  My javascript also looks just like your demo.  I must be missing something, but don't know what it is.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess it could still be a version difference - my demo is using fullCalendar 5.10.1 rather than 5.7. I wouldn't expect such a fundamental difference between point releases, but I guess you never know. Try updating to (at least) that version and see if it helps.